# How to set a border on a list box item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` in which the items are created from an item source, I need every item to have a border but I have no clue where I even set a style for `ListBox` items.

```
<ListBox x:Name="m_list">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                <CustomUserControl />
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="DataToBeEditied" />
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

The custom user controls are a user control I created which edit the data from DataToBeEdited which is an `ObservableCollection` of data

According to what I can find there should be a way but no explanation on how.
How Do I do it?

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet that you are working on so people here can help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="m_list">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                        <CustomUserControl />
                    <Border />
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="DataToBeEditied" />
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, do the following once per `ListBoxItem`:

```
var lbi = new ListBoxItem();
lbi.Width = 60;
lbi.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
lbi.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
lbi.Padding = new Thickness(3, 0, 3, 0);
lbi.Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 3, 0);
lbi.Content = "xyz";
m_list.Items.Add(lbi);
```